# call jquery function inside datalist control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

My issue is i want to open the div onclick the anchor tag inside data-list  control . i search on the google to reach to this function but it is not working
(not open the div when i click on the anchor tag.) i want to know why .

```js
$( function () {
  $('a.detials').on('click', function (ev) {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<asp:DataList ID="dtlRoomsPrice" Visible="false" orizontalAlign="center" runat="server" ShowFooter="False" ShowHeader="False" Width="700px" OnItemDataBound="dtlRoomsDetails_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>


        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="detials">ShowDetails</a>
        <div class="shoow" id="div_ID" style="width:687px;background-color: rgb(247, 239, 216);border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 7px 6px 5px #888888; border: 2px solid gray; display:none;padding: 5px; ">
            <asp:Label ID="lblAmiintiesTxt" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_label" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Amenities %>" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">Amenities</p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblAmiinties" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("Amenities") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="lblCanclText" Width="130" runat="server" CssClass="shbe_label" Visible="false" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Payment and Cancellation policy %>"></asp:Label>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: small;">CancellationPolicy</p>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCancelation" runat="Server" CssClass="shbe_h2" Text='<%# Eval("CancellationPolicyText") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>

        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

try it. It will work.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click",'a.detials', function (ev) {
        $(this).next('div').toggle();
    });
});
```